# My Unity build only looks correct on one computer

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution

When I run my unity exe on the computer I created it on it looks like this:
[CorrectImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k37Iv.jpg)

But when I change nothing and run it on a different computer it looks like this:
[MessedUpImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzaej.jpg)

-I am creating a unity 3D game.
-The pictures uploaded are of the main menu.
-The Unity exe is created by just building it in the Unity editor.
-I assume the problem has to do with my build settings resolution but I have changed them with no luck.

Any help is appreciated!!!

I tried to change the resolution of the build to native resolution, 16:9, 1920:1080, and nothing made a difference. When running it on the other computer it contines to look super zoomed in/blurry.

Answer (score 0):

On your Canvas:

Set the `UI Scale Mode` to `Scale With Screen Size`.
Set the `Reference Resolution` to the resolution you work with in the editor.
Additionally, the `Match Mode` can be adjusted to better suit your specific needs.

Reference for [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)